# Indian National, Transit through Dublin

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland

I am an Indian passport holder, with a US Green card and a UK Work visa. I am booking a round trip ticket from the UK to USA and return to the UK. I want to book the flight that's connecting in Dublin (London to Dublin and Dublin to USA).

I currently don't have an Irish visa. Do I need an Irish transit visa when I arrive in Dublin from UK? Also on the return trip when I arrive in Dublin from US will there be any complications? I don't quite understand the CTA rules.

Please advise.

Comment: Will you need to pass through border control in Ireland? http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit

Answer (score 1):

The [page Traveller cites](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit) answers the question, but is confusing.

Restated: you won't need an Irish visa if all the following is true: a) You arrive and depart DUB at Terminal 2, b) Your arriving flight arrives and your departing flight leaves between 0400 hours and 1600 hours, and c) You arrive and depart on the same calendar day. Each transit (westbound and eastbound) is analyzed separately.

Here's a screenshot of the page in question:

[image: Here's a screenshot]